# File Open dialog does not work in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

A simple

```
<input type="file">
```

is not working in Google Chrome Extension.. Why?

Comment: how exactly it `does not work` ?

Comment: What version? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the file input on a **popup** is buggy on some systems with chrome. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61632

If you're using a popup and need a file input, the workaround im using is:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('init.html')});
});
```

Comment: I have also tried trigger('click') on that input type="file" element... :-( Still no use

Comment: The problem is not triggering the chooser, but showing the chooser itself, as the (chromium implementation of the) dialog would close the popup.